# When is irreducibility of a polynomial over a field equivalent to not having any roots in it?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots, irreducible-polynomials

> When is irreducibility of a polynomial over a field equivalent to not having any roots in it?

Apart from of course, the simple cases when a polynomial $f \in K[x]$ is of degree less than or equal to three. 
One direction is clear: If a polynomial is irreducible in $K$, it can have no roots in it. But the converse is much more bizarre. So I pose:

- What conditions must be put on $f$ so that this happens?
- How does information about $K$ alter this?

I do not even know where to start. Links to any research done in this area is also appreciated :) Thanks, guys!

Comment: an obvious thing: if there are no irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ (i.e. no extensions of $K$ of degree $2$) then you have your property for polynomials of degree $4$. Etc.

Comment: In fact, if there are no degree 2 irreducibles, property holds in degree 5 as well.

Comment: What are examples of non algebraically closed fields with no degree $2$ extensions?

Comment: @Georges, I don't know, but, reasoning naively, if you start with the rationals, and throw in square roots of all rationals, and then square roots of everything in *that* field, and iterate to infinity, you ought to reach a field with no quadratic extensions but not algebraically closed because not containing, for example, the cube root of 2.

Comment: Dear @Gerry: yes, that's an excellent idea,  thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Here are two results (to be found in  Lang's *Algebra*, for example):

1. Let $k$ be a field of any characteristic $\geq 0$ and $p$ an odd
   prime  number (**not** supposed to equal $\operatorname{char} k$) If
   $x^p-a\in k(x)$ has no root in $k$, then it is irreducible  and,
   more strongly, also $x^{p^n}-a$ is  irreducible over $k$ for all 
   integers $n\geq 0$  (Capelli).
2. Over a field $k$ of characteristic $p\gt0$ the polynomial
       $f(x)=x^p-x-a\in k[x]$ is irreducible if and only if it has no root
       in $k$ (Artin-Schreyer).

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer in the strict sense but  a result strongly related to your question.

Let $k$ be a field and let $f(x)\in k[x]\setminus k$ be a polynomial of degree $n\gt0$. We have the equivalence:

> $f(x)$  irreducible over $k\\$ $\iff$ For any extensions $k\subset K$ of degree $\leq n/2$, $f(x)$  has no root in $K$.

**Proof of $\Longrightarrow:$**
Any field $K$ in which $f(x)$ has a root contains a copy of $k[x]/(f(x))$ and has thus degree $\geq n$
**Proof of $\Longleftarrow:$**
If $f(x)$ were reducible one of its irreducible factors $g(x)$ would have degree $deg(g(x))\leq n/2$ and thus the extension $K:=k[x]/(g(x))$ would contain a root of $g(x)$ and *a fortiori* a root of $f(x)$, contradicting the hypothesis.