# Polynomials over a field with characteristic $0$ is square free implies it's coprime with its formal derivative

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $0$, $f \in F[t]$ the polynomial ring over $F$. Show that $f$ is square free implies $ f, f'$ are relatively prime.

---

I know this is actually an if and only if statement, but the other direction is easy. I get stuck on this direction, and I did some search but a lot of materials using extension fields and separable polynomials to get this. But our course haven't reached that far. So can anyone help me with an elementary proof? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I messed up with the direction. That was the easy part, I actually want the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ and $f'$ have a common irreducible factor $p$.  Let $f(t)=p(t)q(t)$.  Then $f'(t) = p(t)q'(t) + p'(t)q(t)$.

Since $p$ is irreducible and $F$ has characteristic zero, $p$ and $p'$ do not have a common factor, so $p(t)$ divides $q(t)$.  In other words, $p^2 \mid f$.

Comment: Thanks! But how did you get $p, p'$ do not have common factor since $F$ has characteristic zero?

Comment: Irreducible polynomials do not have factors, forget common factors with another polynomials!

Comment: @PVanchinathan I think the right question for me to ask is why do we need $F$ to have characteristic zero? Isn't it true that $p,p'$ are relatively prime if $p$ is irreducible in any polynomial ring?

Comment: This is the pure inseparability arising in prime characteristic. Formal derivative $x^p$ is $px^{p-1}$ which is identically zero hence has a common root with every polynomial that has a root in that field.

Comment: @user112564 Almost.  We know that the degree of $p'$ is less than the degree of $p$, which means they share no common factor—unless $p'=0$.  This can happen in nonzero characteristic (specifically, over fields that are not "perfect", so don't try finding counterexamples over finite fields).  For example, let $F=(\mathbb{Z}/q)(X)$.  Then the polynomial $p(t)=t^q-X$ is irreducible, but $p'(t) = qt^{q-1}=0$.

Comment: @User-33433 Oh, that's the point! I got it, thank you so much!

Comment: @Slade, regarding your counterexample: could you explain, please, why the polynomial $p(t) = t^q - X$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}/q)(X)[t]$?

Comment: @Alexey Probably the most straightforward proof is to apply Eisenstein's criterion to the prime $X$ in the PID $(\mathbb{Z}/q)[X]$.  There is also a [standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266171/irreducibility-of-a-polynomial-if-it-has-no-root-capellier) that says that $X^q-\alpha$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/q$ whenever $\alpha$ is not a $q$-th power.