# $f(x)=x^p-a$ is either ireducible or has a root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that for any field $k$ and any $a\in  k$, the polynomial $f(x)=x^p-a$ is either irreducible or has a root.

I think if $\operatorname{Char}k=0$ then $f$ is an irreducible polynomial and if $\operatorname{Char}k=p$ for $p$ a prime number then $f=(x-a)^p$ so $f$ has a root.

This problem is in *Galois Theory*, by Miles Reid.

Comment: If the field is $Z_p$, then $f(a)=0$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403924/xp-c-has-no-root-in-a-field-f-if-and-only-if-xp-c-is-irreducible and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266171/irreducibility-of-polynomial-if-no-root-capelli

Comment: Your first assertion is false; if $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $k=\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is not irreducible for most values of $p$, by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Your argument for characteristic $p$ is only almost correct. The frobenius isomorphism $\phi\colon x\mapsto x^p$ need not leave $a$ untouched. However, we *do* find that $\phi^{-1}(a)$ is a root of $f$. - Also note that the characteristic may be nonzero and stil $\ne p$.